# Как исправить недочёт бота на aiogram, чтобы выводил все сообщения, начиная с заданной даты?

Tags: python, aiogram

Как исправить недочёт бота на aiogram, чтобы выводил все сообщения, начиная с заданной даты? Я ввожу дату боту, он её переводит в объект `datetime`, а далее парсит все сообщения из нужного мне чата. Однако, в конечном файле, записывается только одно сообщение, а не все. Что тут неверно?

```
async def telegram_chat_parser(message: str, user_id_get: int):

    chat_link, date_str = message.split(',')

    date = datetime.strptime(date_str.strip(), '%d.%m.%Y')   

    msg = []
    usernames = []
    name_of_file = str(message.split('/')[-1])

    async with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        entity = await client.get_entity(chat_link)
        all_messages = await client.get_messages(entity, reverse=True, offset_date=date)
        msg = []
        usernames = []
        name_of_file = str(message.split('/')[-1])
    
        for mes in all_messages:
            msg.append(mes.message)
            user_name = mes.from_id

            user_entity = await client.get_entity(user_name)
            usernames.append(f"@{user_entity.username if user_entity is not None else None}")

        df = pd.DataFrame({'Содержание публикации': [title for title in msg],
                       'Автор сообщения': [name for name in usernames]})

        with pd.ExcelWriter(f"{name_of_file}_chat_tg.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"{name_of_file}", index=False)  
            worksheet_page = writer.sheets[f"{name_of_file}"]
            worksheet_page.set_column('A:B', 100) 
            worksheet_page.set_column('B:C', 50) 

        with open(f"{name_of_file}_chat_tg.xlsx", 'rb') as file:
            await bot.send_document(chat_id=user_id_get, document=file)
```